# Why am i getting invalid variable in this code?

Tags: python, text-files

for this code i am trying to swap the two colums around in a text file but when run column2 name 'column2' is not defined

```
file = open("class1.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split() # split line into parts
    if len(parts) > 1:
        column1 = parts[0]
    if len(parts) < 1:
       column2 = parts[1]


file = open("class1.txt", 'w')
file.write(("\n") + str(column2) + str(column1))
file.close()
```

Comment: The error appears to be stemming from the `file.write` portion of the code trying to convert `column2` to a `str` object but it does not exist. Mostly due to how it's setup within your loop.

Comment: I got your problem 1000times before. Check my answer, whatever you do it will throw an error. I wrote the answer.

Comment: You seem to have accidentally deleted your question content, which makes the answers useless; I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You goofed this part up:

> ```
> if len(parts) < 1:
>     column2 = parts[1]
> ```

I'm pretty sure you don't want to access an element that doesn't exist.

But regardless, you don't want to depend on variables that may or may not exist. Be sure to give them some sort of sane default.

Comment: Also, splitting a string will always return at least one element, so the condition will never be true in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to swap the first and second columns.
- Your input file, has the same name as your output file, so the first time you run your program you will overwrite your input file. Use differente names.
- If you use the `with` statement, you avoid open and close, and then open and close as you have now. You can do your process with both files open.

If every line in your input file has two columns, something as simple as this would do the trick:

```
with open ("class1.txt", 'r') as fin, open("class2.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        parts = line.split()
        fout.write(parts[1]+' '+parts[0]+'\n']
```

But if you have some lines with one column and others with more than two, you would have to do something more. How is your file, and how would you need your output?